# Can't mount drive - no such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, mount, ntfs

On the back of this question: [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)
I can't mount my external drive.
I tried both:

```
/dev/disk/sdd1
```

and

```
/dev/disk/by-label/Newx20Volume
```

which is what is what it says in the folder.

Full command tried:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,exec /dev/disk/sdd1 /mnt/NwVol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it's `/dev/sdd1`, not `/dev/disk/sdd1`. And spaces in names aren't usually replaced by hex codes, but just escaped or quoted: `/dev/disk/by-label/New\ Volume` or `"/dev/disk/by-label/New Volume"`. Just use <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion to help you out:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,exec /dev/sd<tab> /mnt/NwVol
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,exec /dev/disk/by-label/New<tab> /mnt/NwVol
```

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the indicated points while typing the commands and the shell will try to complete the path for you.

Comment: I get the message: Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
----Looks like I need to unmount using "umount"

Comment: Now I get:.... fuse: failed to access mountpoint /mnt/New\x20Volume: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok I think I've got it. You have to create a directory (as root) in /mnt/ folder if you want to mount to there.